# UWP app packaging error

Tags: uwp

I am trying to create a package for a UWP app that I have been working on but I keep get the following exception:

```
Internal compiler error: MCG0024:UnresolvableTypeReference Unresolvable type reference 'System.ICloneable' in 'Assembly(Name=mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)' found. Please check the references in your build system. A reference is either missing or an assembly is missing an expected type.
```

this issue is occurring only when I try to create the package in the release mode, it is not happening in the debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your application is using a class or a reference which is not available in UWP. The supported classes between .NET and UWP's .NET Core are not the same and usually issues arise when trying to create the release package.

For example iTextSharp [has blogged about](http://itextpdf.com/blog/itextsharp-and-uwp) this issue before.

The solution is to go through your references and make sure that everything is compatible with UWP apps.

Comment: Thanks Mikael it was iTextSharp causing the problem, I have another problem if you could take a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840014/uwp-file-structure-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long?noredirect=1#comment72851182_42840014